# Including the jquery.min library causes the page not to refresh completely

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, styles, page-refresh

I would like to include the following jquery scripts and stylesheet into my project:

- script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">

  script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">

  link href="~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

My problem is that when I include the scripts, when I navigate to another page, the page does not refresh completely, instead an ajax loader is shown in the middle of the page and then the content of the new page is rendered. I don't want that ajax loader, I want the page to refresh completely like in a normal website. I am including these scripts because of the styling that it gives to my pages. If I only include the stylesheet, the style is not rendered correctly. I have also tried putting a refresh meta tag in my header.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the expected behavior for jQuery Mobile sometimes. Please review:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve We will need more info to assist.

Comment: Can I somehow remove the ajax gif loader and make it refresh automatically?